How to Modify Gallery Preview on Edit Screen on the "Visual" Tab in Classic Editior
I am modifying the gallery_shortcode() function from media.php using a plugin.
How do I make my custom gallery structure show up as the preview on the edit page. I want to change how it displays in this image:

If you inspect this element the gallery preview is inside a wpview div but I cant seem to find where this is generated.
I am using the classic editor. I want to add some css selectors and html tags based on some custom attachment variables. I will likely eventually work on the block editor as well.
I already did this to the actual display of the published gallery, but need some of the elements to show in the editor as well.

can you explain in more detail? Screenshots would be even better, as well as which editor you're asking about, since the technical and visual parts are completely different for galleries in the block editor vs the classic editor, as is the difficulty ( changing how galleries show in the block editor is much easier than in the classic editor ). You'll also need to include details of what you want to change it to, and any JS/CSS that would be needed

I meant the classic editor. I want to add some css selectors and html tags based on some custom attachment variables. I will likely eventually work on the block editor as well.
